# IBindingConfigurationElement - How to implement and add to configuration?

Tags: wcf, configuration, binding

I'm trying to extend WCF with a custom binding which has required that I replace message formatting, encoding and security elements within the WCF stack. To facilitate ease-of-use with this binding, I'd like to make it configurable from a configuration file in the same way as the built-in bindings (i.e. a named element, not `customBinding`).

The WCF standard bindings all inherit from [`StandardBindingElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.configuration.standardbindingelement.aspx), which in turn implements [`IBindingConfigurationElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597216.aspx). If I implement this interface or inherit from the class, how can I make the configuration element available to the WCF configuration system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some digging and found the [`bindingExtensions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa749847%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) element on MSDN. Although the documentation there indicates that you can add bindings this way, I had a peek at my machine.config file and found the following 3.5 bindings registered there:

```
<bindingExtensions>
    <add name="wsHttpContextBinding" type="System.ServiceModel.Configuration.WSHttpContextBindingCollectionElement, System.WorkflowServices, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <add name="netTcpContextBinding" type="System.ServiceModel.Configuration.NetTcpContextBindingCollectionElement, System.WorkflowServices, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <add name="webHttpBinding" type="System.ServiceModel.Configuration.WebHttpBindingCollectionElement, System.ServiceModel.Web, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <add name="basicHttpContextBinding" type="System.ServiceModel.Configuration.BasicHttpContextBindingCollectionElement, System.WorkflowServices, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
</bindingExtensions>
```

These classes function as collections of binding elements, inheriting from the odd [`StandardBindingCollectionElement<TStandardBinding, TBindingConfiguration>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa346281.aspx) class. This looks to be the correct class to inherit from and create an associated [`StandardBindingElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.configuration.standardbindingelement.aspx) from.

The collection is registered using the syntax listed above and should then function exactly the same as built-in WCF bindings.

Answer (score 1):

The post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/07/26/wcf-extensibility-binding-and-binding-element-configuration-extensions.aspx talks about adding configuration extension for bindings and binding elements, you should find more information there.